# modelling the behavior of a particle

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I want to study the evolution of a particle as a function of time, then in dynamical systems, the usual thing to do would be to define the state of the particle. Usually we are able to do this by doing a linear transformation.

Now, let us say that two particles now exist. It is possible that the state of each particle can be studied 'independently' if the particles do not interact at all.

My question is, what if the particles interact with each other? (That is, some sort of information gathering is made from one particle to another so that these particles are not independent from each other?)

What other forms/types of models exist (or what modifications do I make to the usual state representation above) to accommodate these changes?

Your insights will be helpful.

Comment: Models in which particles interact -- through collisions or through inverse-square law forces (gravity, electrostatic) -- are widely used.  I would guess that models where particles do not interact are actually less commonly used (although Monte Carlo simulations would include some examples).

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of state representation you're thinking of? The description "doing a linear transformation" could potentially mean lots of different things.

Comment: I just meant the simple $x_{t+1} = Ax_t$, where $x_t$ is the state of the system at time $t$, and $A$ is some transformation that defines that change from state $x_t$ to $x_{t+1}$. Now, this equation applies only to one particle. Maybe the second particle can take the form of $y_{t+t} = By_t$, where $A$ and $B$ have the same dimensions. So, what if particle $x$ and $y$ interact with each other. How do I represent that nicely?

Comment: If $x_{t}$ represents the state of the entire system (including all particles) at time $t$, then you don't need any change in formalism to represent influences between particles.  These could (would) be rolled up in your transformation $A$.  However if you wanted to separate out states of $n$ particles, $x_t^{(1)}, x_t^{(2)}, \ldots, x_t^{(n)}$ at time $t$, then of course the formalism has to address $x_{t+1}^{(k)}$ as a function of all (or some) of the other (prior) states  as well as $x_t^{(k)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you write a set of coupled differential equations for the locations of the particles.  Each one may be reacting to a potential, but there is also an interaction force.  If $a$ is the position of the first particle, you have an equation like $a''=f(a)+g(a-b)$ where $f$ represents the potential and $g$ is the interaction force.  You have a similar equation for the second particle.  In 3D you now have six differential equations, one for the acceleration of each particle in each axis.